# Allow Open ERP Accounting Module Customers to login

Tags: odoo

I want the Customers in Accounting modules to have login access to view his transactions. Or may be can I have the other way around where a login user can be used as a Customer while creating invoices.

Answer (score 1):

The [`share` module](http://apps.openerp.com/addon/684) will let you share any OpenERP document with business partners. You can find a user guide and screen cast on [snippetbucket.com](http://www.snippetbucket.com/2011/11/22/openerp-share-module/).